# How to get a reference to a string property in C#

Tags: c#, string, immutability

Say I have a class with three string properties:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string Bar1 { get; set; }
  public string Bar2 { get; set; }
  public string Bar3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now say I want to assign to one of the string properties, but that which of the three properties I assign to depends upon some condition. Knowing that strings are supposedly reference types, I might be tempted to write some code like this:

```
string someString;
if (condition1) someString = foo.Bar1;
else if (condition2) someString = foo.Bar2;
else if (condition3) someString = foo.Bar3;
someString = "I can't do that, Dave.";
```

This doesn't work. I know it's got something to do with string immutability (at least I think it does) but I haven't any idea how to do it.

Strings basically confuse the bejesus out of me.

Um, yeah, so my question is what's the most concise way to do this?

Comment: The question says "Now say I want to assign *to* one of the string properties" but you are clearly assigning *from* the properties to someString, not *to* the properties.

Comment: Because there is no `else` prior to the last line of code, `someString` will always contain the text `"I can't do that, Dave."` after the block executes.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work other than you always ending up with someString equalling "I can't do that, Dave." because you missed the last else out :)

Comment: He wants foo.Bar1, foo.Bar2 or foo.Bar3 to equal "T can't..." at the end. somestring is supposed to be a pointer to the property he wants to update.

Comment: Sorry, my question must have been ambiguous. I meant I want to assign TO the property (as Andrew and Fredrik inferred). The code needs to establish which of the three properties to assign to.

Comment: Yes, thank you Chris Sainty! That's what I mean!

Comment: You can't do that. You can use StringBuilder instead of the string to virtualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would probably just go ahead and assign the property:

```
string value = "I can't do that, Dave.";
if (condition1) foo.Bar1 = value;
else if (condition2) foo.Bar2 = value;
else if (condition3) foo.Bar3 = value;
```

If you *really* want to use the approach you suggest, you can wrap it in a delegate I guess:

```
Action<string> assignString;
if (condition1) assignString = s => foo.Bar1 = s;
else if (condition2) assignString = s => foo.Bar2 = s;
else if (condition3) assignString = s => foo.Bar3 = s;
assignString("I can't do that, Dave.");
```

...but in this case that would only make things unnecessarily complex. For the kind of scenario that is described in the question, I can't think of any reason you would want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for spell checking @spender :-)

Comment: You're right. I'm trying to do something needlessly complex. But if a string was a reference type in the same sense that, say, a class is, then it would totally work... I think.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it like this:

```
string someString = "I can't do that, Dave.";
if (condition1) foo.Bar1 = someString;
else if (condition2) foo.Bar2 = someString;
else if (condition3) foo.Bar3 = someString;
```

C# tries to make strings as easy as possible to work with. They are primitive types, so you don't really need to worry about mutability or memory or addresses or anything like that.

Comment: Correct. It would be possible to work some reflection magic to get a PropertyInfo object for the property to assign; however, this solution is both simple and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it like this:

EDITED **

var someString = (condition1) ? foo.Bar1 : (condition2) ? foo.Bar2 : (condition3) ? foo.Bar3 : "I can't do that Dave";

Let me know how you go.

Comment: That's broken code. It's `condition?trueVal:falseVal` not `condition:..?..`  If you format your code so it doesn't invoke a horizontal scroll bar, it's much easier to read.

Comment: This answer is also based on a misinterpretation of my question (for which I accept responsibility). Please see my comments under the question.

Comment: I would be having a little pow-wow with anyone in my team who wrote that code.

Comment: lol. Are you objecting to the syntax error, or the big one-liner? Just in case I end up working for you.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have fixed it, was sitting on train, and I haven't used this syntax for a while.